# Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked at a bunch of other threads with the same error, however mine seems to be a bit different. I've already checked for missing commas and stuff.

This is the original code that doesn't work:

```
SELECT `color_name`, `dna_sample` FROM `horse_color_base` WHERE `dna_sample` = $dna
```

However, if you change `$dna` to `"eeee aaaa"` (what the value of `$dna` is) it works perfectly.

```
SELECT `color_name`, `dna_sample` FROM `horse_color_base` WHERE `dna_sample` = 'eeee aaaa'
```

The validation error reads:

> Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'aaaa' at line 1

It seems like it's breaking up the $dna variable, which is screwing everything up.

Thoughts or ideas on how to make this thing work with the variable?

I'm using collation `latin1_general_cs` for the `dna` and `dna_sample` columns because I need them to be case sensitive.

Comment: The variable is unquoted. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: For this to work as you have it, the value of `$dna` would have to _literally_ include the quotes `$dna = "'eeee aaaa'";` which is very uncommon. More common is `WHERE dna_sample = '$dna'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Michael Berkowski comments, quote the variable:

```
WHERE `dna_sample` = '$dna'
```

Writing a query this way is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/50552).  It's almost always better to write a query with bound parameters:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM horse_color_base WHERE dna_sample = :dna');
$stmt->execute(array('dna' => $dna));
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Every time I think I'm starting to get the hang of PHP, something weird like this happens. Helps to have a great StackOverflow community!